# Apache setHandler only only works on index

Tags: php, apache2

I am using docker for local development on a PHP powered craft website. My shared host requires a `SetHandler php70-cgi` directive, but the version of apache in the official PHP container does not have php-cgi and does not interpret PHP scripts. Because the container is development only, and not an attempt to 1:1 replicate production, I'm attempting to work around this with a custom apache config that sets an `InDocker` request variable:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/craft/public
  SetEnv InDocker true

  <!-- ... more config -->
</VirtualHost>
```

And an `.htaccess` in my public folder that conditionally checks for the request env and only runs the:

```
Header set InDocker "%{InDocker}e"
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  <If "!reqenv('InDocker') =~ /true/">
    Header set IfMatch "We are not in docker"
    SetHandler php70-cgi
  </If>
  Header set FilesMatch "yo"
</FilesMatch>
```

When I make a request to the root of my application, things render correctly and I see the following headers:

```
http -h :4020/
InDocker: true
FilesMatch: yo
```

However, if I make a request to another path, things do not render correctly and I can see the following headers are set:

```
http -h :4020/
InDocker: true
FilesMatch: yo
IfMatch: We are not in a container
```

Is there a way I can get this to work using my `If` or a better way to accomplish conditionally using `SetHandler`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this to work using `SetEnv` and `if reqenv` so I had to fall back to using `Define` and `IfDefine`.

I added `Define InDocker` to my container's apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/public
  Define InDocker

  <Directory /var/www/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And then used `IfDefine` in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfDefine !InDocker>
  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler php70-cgi
  </FilesMatch>
</IfDefine>
```

This allows me to keep things as-is on my shared host and use the same `.htacess` for development.